# Batch script does not echo contents of a variable and pause not working

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am working on a script which iterates over every file in a specific folder and reads some information from, and numbers each.

So I am running over the files with a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) and that is working correctly. Now I added a variable `i` which should increment on each iteration of the loop.

I used `set /a i=0` and inside the for-loop `set /a i+=1` and this `Set` command does print the number to console. My problem now is that the `set` command prints the number, but when I echo the number with `echo %i%` it will always print `0` and not the increasing value. I also tried `echo !i!` but that does not work at all. It just prints `!i!` in the console.

I also added a `pause` command to the end of the script, but that gets ignored entirely.

This is my batch script:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /a i=0

for /r %%n in (Links\*.lnk) do (

    set /a i+=1
    echo.
    echo [Button!i!Back]
    get.bat "%%n"

)

pause
```

This is an example of the output:

```
45
[Button!i!Back]
#@#HudIcons\VLC media player.ico
D:\Programme\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe
```

I also just realized, that for the first time the loop runs, the `!i!` does work correctly and prints the number, but not afterwards.

I know that I should probably not be calling the other batch file like this, but that is temporary.

Any ideas why this is behaving so weird?

Comment: Without seeing `get.bat`, we'd be guessing, but since it's a batch file, you need to `CALL get.bat ...` in order to provide a return location, otherwise batch simply jumps to the executed batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would be easier for you without the `Set /A` incrementing method, and therefore no need for delayed expansion. The alternative methodology could involve using `findstr.exe` to provide the counting:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%G In ('Dir /B /S /A:-D "Links\*.lnk" ^
 2^> NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /EILN ".lnk"') Do (Echo=
    Echo [Button%%GBack]
    Call "get.bat" "%%H")
Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You use percentages symbol to call a variable `%Variable%`
and to echo it `echo %variable%`
to set one `set variable=value` Hope this helps you.